# Can 'das' be used in place of 'dass' at all?

Tags: spelling, grammar-identification

I have read many sentences on Facebook written by Germans and still can't figure out why they are using *das* instead of *dass* in such sentences. For example, a joke I just read:

> Jedesmal wenn ein Mädchen sagt, das sie durch einen Unfall schwanger wurde, stelle ich mir immer sowas vor.

Is this a colloquial usage, or what? What does *das* refer to in this sentence? Do people sometimes use *das* instead of *dass* in the non-standard written language?

Comment: Your questions in the last days all deal with the same fact. People simply don't know to write correctly ;-) It's sad, a shame, whatever. But it is true.

Comment: Same as "they're", "their" and "there" in English (or "you're" vs. "your"), simply wrong.

Comment: Mixing up "seit" and "seid" is also a mistake, that I often see in comments on social media. Some may just don't know how to write correctly, others don't bother proofreading their comments. Result is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is simply wrong. *Dass* and *das* can never be exchanged, and I do not really understand the frequency of misspelling.  The only reasons I see are, that both words sound very similar and not everybody cares to write correctly.

Comment: They do not "sound very similar". They sound exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That was helpful. I wanted to be sure that it's simply a mistake like you said.

Comment: @fdb: In my opinion *exactly the same* is a subset of *very similar*. I chose the latter, since due to my knowledge some regions use a voiced *s* for the article/reflexive pronoun only.

Comment: Regading pronunciation, I would say that in pure theatre and broadcasting pronunciation, *das* and *dass* sound exactly the same. However, you may find a slight difference between them in certain regions of the German speaking world (I am not speaking of dialects though). A test is to ask people to pronounce it very slowly. In certain regions the will pronounce "daaaaß" versus "daßßßßß" (the difference being the length of the vowel). As for the writing: this is just negligence or incapability of orthography.

Comment: Unfortunately many people make the mistake of writing 'das' in place of 'dass'. Often they also omit the comma, adding a second mistake and making the first harder to recognize.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. For a non-native speaker like me it is hard to recognize such mistakes easily only because the people who make them are native speakers. I always consider a possibility of another explanation other than a mistake when native speakers write.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann. I think these are hyper-correct spelling pronunciations, like when people pronounce the h in gehen.

Comment: Note that even the big newspapers often get it wrong since they dropped their editorial offices some years ago.